# Azure Databricks community edition COPY INTO command error

Tags: delta-lake, databricks-community-edition

I have been getting the following error upon running the COPY INTO command in Databricks Community edition:

Error in SQL statement: UnsupportedOperationException: com.databricks.backend.daemon.data.client.DBFSV1.createAtomicIfAbsent(path: Path)**
com.databricks.backend.common.rpc.DatabricksExceptions$SQLExecutionException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: com.databricks.backend.daemon.data.client.DBFSV1.createAtomicIfAbsent(path: Path)
at com.databricks.tahoe.store.EnhancedDatabricksFileSystemV1.createAtomicIfAbsent(EnhancedFileSystem.scala:324)
at com.databricks.spark.sql.streaming.AWSCheckpointFileManager.createAtomicIfAbsent(DatabricksCheckpointFileManager.scala:159)
at com.databricks.spark.sql.streaming.DatabricksCheckpointFileManager.createAtomicIfAbsent(DatabricksCheckpointFileManager.scala:60)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.RocksDBFileManager.zipToDfsFile(RocksDBFileManager.scala:510)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.RocksDBFileManager.saveCheckpointToDfs(RocksDBFileManager.scala:189)
at com.databricks.sql.rocksdb.CloudRocksDB.$anonfun$open$5(CloudRocksDB.scala:467)
at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.timeTakenMs(Utils.scala:680)
at com.databricks.sql.rocksdb.CloudRocksDB.timeTakenMs(CloudRocksDB.scala:543)
at com.databricks.sql.rocksdb.CloudRocksDB.$anonfun$open$2(CloudRocksDB.scala:455)
at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.$anonfun$recordOperation$1(UsageLogging.scala:330)
at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.executeThunkAndCaptureResultTags$1(UsageLogging.scala:424)
at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.$anonfun$recordOperationWithResultTags$4(UsageLogging.scala:444)
at com.databricks.logging.Log4jUsageLoggingShim$.$anonfun$withAttributionContext$1(Log4jUsageLoggingShim.scala:33)
at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:62)
at com.databricks.logging.AttributionContext$.withValue(AttributionContext.scala:94)
at com.databricks.logging.Log4jUsageLoggingShim$.withAttributionContext(Log4jUsageLoggingShim.scala:31)
at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionContext(UsageLogging.scala:205)
at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionContext$(UsageLogging.scala:204)
at com.databricks.spark.util.PublicDBLogging.withAttributionContext(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:20)
at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags(UsageLogging.scala:240)
at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags$(UsageLogging.scala:225)
at com.databricks.spark.util.PublicDBLogging.withAttributionTags(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:20)
at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.recordOperationWithResultTags(UsageLogging.scala:419)
at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.recordOperationWithResultTags$(UsageLogging.scala:339)
at com.databricks.spark.util.PublicDBLogging.recordOperationWithResultTags(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:20)
at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.recordOperation(UsageLogging.scala:330)
at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.recordOperation$(UsageLogging.scala:302)
at com.databricks.spark.util.PublicDBLogging.recordOperation(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:20)
at com.databricks.spark.util.PublicDBLogging.recordOperation0(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:57)
at com.databricks.spark.util.DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.recordOperation(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:137)
at com.databricks.spark.util.UsageLogger.recordOperation(UsageLogger.scala:73)
at com.databricks.spark.util.UsageLogger.recordOperation$(UsageLogger.scala:60)
at com.databricks.spark.util.DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.recordOperation(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:98)
at com.databricks.spark.util.UsageLogging.recordOperation(UsageLogger.scala:431)
at com.databricks.spark.util.UsageLogging.recordOperation$(UsageLogger.scala:410)
at com.databricks.sql.rocksdb.CloudRocksDB.recordOperation(CloudRocksDB.scala:55)
at com.databricks.sql.rocksdb.CloudRocksDB.recordRocksDBOperation(CloudRocksDB.scala:562)
at com.databricks.sql.rocksdb.CloudRocksDB.$anonfun$open$1(CloudRocksDB.scala:447)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ProgressReporter$.withStatusCode(ProgressReporter.scala:377)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ProgressReporter$.withStatusCode(ProgressReporter.scala:363)
at com.databricks.spark.util.SparkDatabricksProgressReporter$.withStatusCode(ProgressReporter.scala:34)
at com.databricks.sql.rocksdb.CloudRocksDB.open(CloudRocksDB.scala:447)
at com.databricks.sql.rocksdb.CloudRocksDB.(CloudRocksDB.scala:83)
at com.databricks.sql.rocksdb.CloudRocksDB$.open(CloudRocksDB.scala:615)
at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.commands.copy.CopyIntoRocksDB.(CopyIntoRocksDB.scala:45)
at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.commands.copy.CopyIntoRocksDB$.apply(CopyIntoRocksDB.scala:39)
at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.commands.copy.CopyIntoRocksDB$.withDeduplicator(CopyIntoRocksDB.scala:87)
at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.commands.copy.CopyIntoCommandEdge.processExactlyOnce(CopyIntoCommandEdge.scala:271)
at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.commands.copy.CopyIntoCommandEdge.runWriteMode(CopyIntoCommandEdge.scala:312)
at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.commands.copy.CopyIntoCommandEdge.$anonfun$run$1(CopyIntoCommandEdge.scala:301)
at com.databricks.sql.acl.CheckPermissions$.trusted(CheckPermissions.scala:1585)
at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.commands.copy.CopyIntoCommandEdge.run(CopyIntoCommandEdge.scala:297)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:80)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:78)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.executeCollect(commands.scala:89)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$$nestedInanonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1$1.$anonfun$applyOrElse$1(QueryExecution.scala:160)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$8(SQLExecution.scala:239)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:386)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$1(SQLExecution.scala:186)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:968)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withCustomExecutionEnv(SQLExecution.scala:141)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:336)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$$nestedInanonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:160)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$$nestedInanonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:156)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$1(TreeNode.scala:575)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:167)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:575)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:268)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:264)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:551)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1(QueryExecution.scala:156)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.allowInvokingTransformsInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:324)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.eagerlyExecuteCommands(QueryExecution.scala:156)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:141)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:132)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.(Dataset.scala:225)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.$anonfun$ofRows$2(Dataset.scala:104)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:968)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:101)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.$anonfun$sql$1(SparkSession.scala:803)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:968)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:798)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.sql(SQLContext.scala:695)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.SQLDriverLocal.$anonfun$executeSql$1(SQLDriverLocal.scala:91)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:293)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.SQLDriverLocal.executeSql(SQLDriverLocal.scala:37)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.SQLDriverLocal.repl(SQLDriverLocal.scala:145)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.$anonfun$execute$11(DriverLocal.scala:605)
at com.databricks.logging.Log4jUsageLoggingShim$.$anonfun$withAttributionContext$1(Log4jUsageLoggingShim.scala:33)
at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:62)
at com.databricks.logging.AttributionContext$.withValue(AttributionContext.scala:94)
at com.databricks.logging.Log4jUsageLoggingShim$.withAttributionContext(Log4jUsageLoggingShim.scala:31)
at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionContext(UsageLogging.scala:205)
at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionContext$(UsageLogging.scala:204)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionContext(DriverLocal.scala:60)
at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags(UsageLogging.scala:240)
at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags$(UsageLogging.scala:225)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionTags(DriverLocal.scala:60)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.execute(DriverLocal.scala:582)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.$anonfun$tryExecutingCommand$1(DriverWrapper.scala:615)
at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:213)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.tryExecutingCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:607)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.executeCommandAndGetError(DriverWrapper.scala:526)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.executeCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:561)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInnerLoop(DriverWrapper.scala:431)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInner(DriverWrapper.scala:374)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.run(DriverWrapper.scala:225)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.SQLDriverLocal.executeSql(SQLDriverLocal.scala:130)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.SQLDriverLocal.repl(SQLDriverLocal.scala:145)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.$anonfun$execute$11(DriverLocal.scala:605)
at com.databricks.logging.Log4jUsageLoggingShim$.$anonfun$withAttributionContext$1(Log4jUsageLoggingShim.scala:33)
at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:62)
at com.databricks.logging.AttributionContext$.withValue(AttributionContext.scala:94)
at com.databricks.logging.Log4jUsageLoggingShim$.withAttributionContext(Log4jUsageLoggingShim.scala:31)
at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionContext(UsageLogging.scala:205)
at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionContext$(UsageLogging.scala:204)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionContext(DriverLocal.scala:60)
at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags(UsageLogging.scala:240)
at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags$(UsageLogging.scala:225)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionTags(DriverLocal.scala:60)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.execute(DriverLocal.scala:582)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.$anonfun$tryExecutingCommand$1(DriverWrapper.scala:615)
at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:213)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.tryExecutingCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:607)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.executeCommandAndGetError(DriverWrapper.scala:526)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.executeCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:561)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInnerLoop(DriverWrapper.scala:431)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInner(DriverWrapper.scala:374)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.run(DriverWrapper.scala:225)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

I already created a  table with the schema, and now trying to copy the data from Data Lake to delta table, but not been able to copy it using COPY INTO command. Does anybody know its solution?

The command I am executing is:

%sql
COPY INTO bronze_table

FROM "/mnt/streamingdatastorage/datastorage/Bronze/Table1"

FILEFORMAT = DELTA

Comment: Can you please include the complete error message?

Comment: You can check my post now, I have added complete error message.

Comment: Can you check if this works: insert into bronze_table select * from delta.`/mnt/streamingdatastorage/datastorage/Bronze/Table1`` (Path enclosed with in backticks)

Comment: I tried it, it's giving a different error: AnalysisException: Cannot write to 'spark_catalog.default.bronzetable', not enough data columns; target table has 47 column(s) but the inserted data has 9 column(s). Don't know why that's the case, since my data has same number of columns

Comment: try querying both source and target tables to recheck if that is the case

Comment: Alright....but any solution for this error which I posted? Does community edition only support DBFSv1? Do you know anything about it?

Comment: The problem might be with community edition supporting DBFSv1. This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70333366/databricks-cannot-save-stream-checkpoint) addresses a similar issue. Please check if it helps.

Comment: Yes I followed this thread before. I tried running the commands mentioned in the thread to fix it, but didn't work. I guess it is pointing towards the fact that community edition works on DBFSv1.